# Click is not working for SVG tag in iPhone with ADA enabled (voice over) and also Its is not reading

Tags: javascript, svg

For SVG tag click event is working normally in desktop and also in iPhone.

But when ADA mode is ON SVG tag click event is not working.

I have searched many but haven't find any solution for this blocker issue.

Please verify the below link for SVG same click event.

[Svg click events not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671895/svg-click-events-not-working-properly)

```js
function one() {
    alert("1");
}
function two() {
    alert("2");
}
function three() {
    alert("3");
}
function four() {
    alert("4");
}
```

```html
<svg style="position: absolute;height:auto;width:auto;">
<path d="m 25.857864,25.857865 a 20,20 0 0 1 28.284271,-1e-6 L 40,40 Z" onClick="one()"/>
<path
   d="m 25.857864,-54.142135 a 20,20 0 0 1 28.284271,-10e-7 L 40,-40 Z" 
   transform="rotate(90)" onClick="two()"/>
<path
   d="m -54.142136,-54.142135 a 20,20 0 0 1 28.284271,-10e-7 L -40,-40 Z" 
   transform="scale(-1)" onClick="three()" />

<path 
   d="m 25.857864,25.857865 a 20,20 0 0 1 28.284271,-1e-6 L 40,40 Z" 
   transform="matrix(0,1,1,0,0,0)" onClick="four()"/>
</svg>
```

I have loaded the same in iPhone with ADA on mode, click is not working also it is not reading anything.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and read [ask].

Comment: @Jasper de Vries Can you verify now and solve my issue

Comment: I am going to presume ADA is VoiceOver/JAWS, so basically accessibility (or `ARIA`). `<path />` elements aren't tab accessible by default, nor are they 'clickable' by default. You will have to simulate a keyboard click on anything that isn't an `<a href="">`, by listening for `enter` or `space` `keyup` events, and make them tabable by adding a `tabindex="0"` to them.